# Display Columns To Rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause, unpivot

I have a table that looks like this:

```
AccountNumber, Warning01, Warning01ExpirationDate, Warning02, Waring02ExpirtionDate, .....
1234, 3,'2017-09-06',0, null
78976, 1,'2015-04-03',2,null
```

I would like to show the result as follow:

```
AccountNumber,Warning,ExpirationDate
1234,2,'2017-09-06'
78976,1,'2015-04-03'
78976,2,null
```

if the warning is 0 or null, I want to ignore it.

any ideas?

Comment: Why did Warning01 value 3 become 2?

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL, just use `cross apply` and `values()` to unpivot your dataset:

```
select x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (values 
    (t.accountNumber, t.warning01, t.warning01expirationDate),
    (t.accountNumber, t.warning02, t.warning02expirationDate)
) as x(accountNumber, warning, expirationDate)
where x.warning <> 0
```